# Compass stopped working after update

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, compass-sass, breakpoint-sass

After the release of breakpoint 2.2.0 yesterday, I updated sass and also had to update json to 1.8.1, and so on...

For the entire update-marathon I ended up installing xcode and command line tools and rvm. Also I learned about bundler and how to update through that.

I'm on a MBP running OS X 10.7.5

However, now I can't get compass to watch a project anymore:

```
$ compass watch project
```

> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
>   Errno::EACCES on line 1039 of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:
>   Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/breakpoint-2.2.0/stylesheets/.listen_test

After changing: `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin` to `PATH=$PATH:~/.rvm/bin`
in the `.bashrc`, I got it working once. Now, a day later it's not working anymore.

Can someone please help me, get everything up and running again?

Answer (score 0):

Your output shows clearly that you are not using rvm and it seems it was your intent. You need to find the ruby you installed with rvm:

```
rvm list
```

and use it:

```
rvm use ruby
```

replace `ruby` with the version you installed.

Make sure to read all the messages rvm prints, this might be important for your process.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now i'm bumping into a new issue:
´$ compass watch´
LoadError on line ["55"] of /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- toolkit´

Comment: That means you do not have the Toolkit gem installed under your current Ruby path. I'd suggest installing Bundler (http://bundler.io/) and managing project gem versions with that to ensure you always have the proper gems installed, available, and used.